# Type promotion rule for i4 and S8 in numpy doc

Tags: numpy

I have come across this example from the numpydoc:

```
np.promote_types('i4', 'S8')
dtype('S11')
```

Basically, I cant understand the following:

An i4 takes 4 bytes and an S8 takes 8 bytes. So why - in terms of memory - do I need a S11 to accomodate both types? I would have expected S8 as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S8 is a character string. Therefore the relevant case to think about when choosing a dtype to accomodate both i4 and S8 is representing the longest number possible in i4 as a character string.

To represent -2,147,483,648 as a string you need 11 characters. That's why you get S11 as the result.

Comment: Thank you - I understand this reasoning. However, for me this is not what the usual term "cast" is supposed to be. Because this involves a transformation under the hood, whereas a cast usually views the bit pattern just in a different way - but leaves it untouched. So I find the phrase: "Returns the data type with the smallest size and smallest scalar kind to which both type1 and type2 may be safely cast." slightly confusing.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that casting is just reassigning bits to some other datatype. In that case going from Float to Int or going the other way would just mess everything up always. You usually have to work the bits in some way to go from one datatype to another

Answer (score 0):

An example of 'viewing' the same bit pattern as 'i4' and 'S8' is:

```
In [213]: np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype='i4').view('S8')
Out[213]: array([b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02', b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04'], dtype='|S8')
```

The 4*4=16 data-buffer can be viewed as two 'S8'

Casting/type promoting occurs when we try to make a new array, such as with concatenate, from the integer array and the string one:

```
In [214]: np.hstack([np.array([1],'i4'),np.array(['testings'],dtype='S8')])
Out[214]: array([b'1', b'testings'], dtype='|S11')
```

or with the default unicode string format:

```
In [215]: np.array([1, 'testings'])
Out[215]: array(['1', 'testings'], dtype='<U11')
```